# set a variable reference as calculation

Tags: variables, reference

Can i declare a variable and then set the reference as a formula(calculation)?

```
 Dim difference As String
  Set difference = Txthours.Value - Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2").Value
```

Comment: No.  Make a function.

Comment: @SLaks sorry im very new to vb could you maybe give me an example as to how to create a function?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vb+function